# List of $(Things) you can have in Visual Studio's Project Properties

Tags: visual-studio

I know of the following:

- `$(ConfigurationName)`: for example "Debug" or "Release"
- `$(SolutionDir)`: directory of the solution
- `$(PlatformName)`: "Win32" or "x64"

Are there any others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Macros for Build Commands and Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) in MSDN for a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit Edit... then Macros you'll get a list of the supported properties, including InputDir, InputFileName, InputPath (ditto for TargetXXX).  Also, rather usefully you can refer to `$(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)`

Comment: In a C++ project, select the project in the solution explorer, right-click Properties then for example pick Configuration Properties -> General -> Output directory.  Click the disclosure control on the right of the edit box and choose Edit, then you'll get a dialog with the Macros button.